# Augmenting images in a dataset - encountering ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'

Tags: python, neural-network, valueerror

I'm in a beginner neural networks class and am really struggling.

I have a dataset of images that isn't big enough to train my network with, so I'm trying to augment them (rotate/noise addition etc.) and add the augmented images onto the original set. I'm following the code found on Medium: https://medium.com/@thimblot/data-augmentation-boost-your-image-dataset-with-few-lines-of-python-155c2dc1baec

However, I'm encountering `ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'`

Not sure what this error means or how to go about solving it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
import random
from scipy import ndarray
import skimage as sk
from skimage import transform
from skimage import util

path1 = "/Users/.../"
path2 = "/Users/.../"
listing = os.listdir(path1)  

num_files_desired = 1000

image = [os.path.join(path2, f) for f in os.listdir(path2) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path2, f))]

num_generated_files = 0
while num_generated_files <= num_files_desired:
    image_path = random.choice(image)
    image_to_transform = sk.io.imread(image_path)
```

```
    137     if format is None:
    138         raise ValueError(
--> 139             "Could not find a format to read the specified file " "in mode %r" % mode
    140         )
    141 

ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see few possiblities. Before passing to them. I'd like to express what is your error. It's basically an indicator that your images cannot be read by `sk.io.imread()`. Let me pass to the possible things to do:

- Your `[os.path.join(path2, f) for f in os.listdir(path2) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path2, f))]` part may not give the image path correctly. You have to correct it manually. If so, you can manually give the exact folder without doing such kind of a loop. Just simply use `os.listdir()` and read the files manually.
- You can also use `glob` to read the files that having same extension like `.jpg` or stuff.
- Your files may be corrupted. You can simply eliminate them by using `PIL` and read the images with `PIL` like `image = Image.open()` first and use `image.verify()` method.
- Try to read about `sk.io.imread(filename, plugin=''` the plugin part may resolve your issue.

Hope it helps.